supercite punctuation not superscripts when using kpfonts-otf with Lua/XeLaTeX
I am trying to use XeLaTeX with kpfonts-otf, but for some reason the punctuation in the supercitations is "normalscript"(?), making the citations look a little out of place.
MWE:
\documentclass{memoir}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % for pdfLaTeX
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for pdfLaTeX

\usepackage{fontspec} %not in pdfLaTeX

\usepackage{kpfonts-otf} %without the "-otf" for pdfLaTeX 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=chem-angew]{biblatex}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{ref1,
  author = {Latex, Lion},
  year = {2024},
  title = {How to tikz?},
}
@article{ref2,
    author = {Duck, Writer},
    year = {2023},
    title = {duckuments},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
Citing \supercite{ref1, ref2}.
test math: $^{\textup{[]}}$
\printbibliography
\end{document}

In Lua/XeLaTeX the above produces:

In pdfLaTeX:

In the Lua/XeLateX versions, the brackets and punctuation around the numbers in the supercite are for some reason not superscripts?
I've tried looking for a workaround, but not been able to find anything, so any help is welcome.

You can try \makeatletter\disable@package@load{realscripts}{}\makeatother

This is a bug in the OTF version of the Kpfonts (brackets and comma are missing in the superscripts). I will fix it asap. Meanwhile not loading the realscripts package is a possible workaround as pointed out by Ulrike.

@DanielFlipo imho it would be better not to load realscripts by default. Support for real superscripts is so patchy in various fonts and you have no control about what other fonts a document loads.

@UlrikeFisher Hum… kpfonts-otf.sty is meant for people who do not want to bother with details, they should get the real subs/superscripts available in the kpfonts without further ado.  But I will add an option fakedscripts to disable realscripts.sty loading.   People wanting to use part of the kpfonts together with other text fonts (possibly conflicting with realscripts) can use the notext option of kpfonts-otf (then realscripts is not loaded) or load fontspec and define their fonts with \setmainfont, etc. as described in the documentation.

@UlrikeFischer This works, thanks. As a note (and sensibly) it needs to be done before the \uspackage{kpfonts-otf} command. Will yo write an answer so I can accept it?

@DanielFlipo I just checked for the case of n > 2 consecutive references in one supercite (I.E. i–j) and it seems that the en and possibly em dash is also missing.

@DanielFlipo but people need to bother with details as soon as realscripts is loaded! That is the main problem with the package (and with the concept of real scripts in general). You really have to check for every char that you use in a superscript if it has a real script variant. If you want to make life easy for the user, avoid the package. If you want to use it: put a large warning into the doc about side effects and include advice how to handle wrong mixes in superscripts.

Using faked superscripts (or faked small caps) is a poor man's option.  Look at the pdflatex outpout: the digits and the brackets are too big and too thin.  I'll provide the missing superscripts for the OpenType version of the kpfonts; I think it is worth the pain.

@DanielFlipo I agree that the OT font looks better, would it maybe be possible to fall back to the LaTeX method if a glyph doesn't exist? That would be the best of both worlds no?

Unfortunately realscripts.sty does not provide this kind of automatic fallback.  Imho OpenType fonts should provide the 10 digits, lowercase Latin letters, and some more for supercite: punctuation, parentheses, brackets, braces(?), endash, ... as superscripts, there is no 'official list' afaik. I will manage so that no superscript is missing in the kpfonts (OT version).   I will also add an option 'fakescripts' to kpfonts-otf.sy just in case…

@DanielFlipo I know that real scripts looks better. But that is not my point. The problem is that even if there were an "official" list, people wouldn't stick to it. They put everything into \textsuperscript, including greek letters, stars, or emojis, or .... and once the realscript package has been loaded it is hard for a user hard to undo it.

@UlrikeFisher Sorry, I disagree about what the default should be. I will provide a 'fakedscript' option for those people who misuse superscripts.  Not loading realscripts by default would 1. be a regression for users who  like better looking digits (for footnote calls) or latin letters (f.i. abbreviation of Mademoiselle or Madame in French) and superscripts users (once the missing glyphs added) 2. break the upward compatibility.

@DanielFlipo my name is Fischer not Fisher, so I didn't see your ping.

Sorry Ulrike, it was a typo :-(

As mentionned in the comments, it is a bug in the OTF version of the Kpfonts (brackets and comma are missing in the superscripts). This is fixed in version 0.63 which has been uploaded to CTAN today (2024/05/02), kpfonts-otf should now support supercitations.
A new option fakedscripts has also been added to the kpfonts-otf.sty package, it prevents the loading of realscripts.sty (loaded by default) thus reverting to the way pdflatex works for super/subscripts (i.e. just scaling
down the corresponding character and moving it up or down).  This way all characters available in font may be used as super/subscripts but the result is suboptimal; specially designed super/subscripts look better… but only a limited set of characters is available (usually all digits, all lowercase
ASCII letters, some delimiters, etc.). Compare the default

and (with the fakedscripts option)

Please be aware that the realscripts package provides starred versions \textsuperscript*{} and \textsubscript*{} to input missing characters, f.i.  \textsuperscript*{\#} prints a (faked) # superscript as this character is not available as real superscript in the kpfonts:

